# How is "Tier" difficulty calculated?

Tags: wrath-and-glory

After reading through the Core Rulebook, I have noticed something about the Tier system the game uses. From my understanding, this works similarly to the "Challenge Rating" system in D&D. The Tiers go from 1 to 5, which affect everything from playable classes, stats, enemy and task difficulty, usable equipment, etc.

However, once I reached the Bestiary, having a look at some of the monsters, the Tier is suggested that "Elite" monsters scale at Tier 5+. I have only seen the Tier lists go up to 5.

There is a table listed as "Escalation Tiers" (Core Rulebook p.57), which might suggest that you add more to the dice pool and "difficulty" of the monster: I.e. a Tier 6 monster would be Tier 5 (+8) plus Tier 1 (+4) - meaning the "difficulty" of the monster would be +12?

Or, since the Tier escalation goes up by 1 for each Tier, a Tier 5 monster would be +8, and a Tier 6 would be +9?

So how are challenges, monsters, etc calculated above Tier 5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### This is managed at the GM's discretion

Basically, the Tier list provided only refers to the primary system setting, and anything beyond this is for *if* the players and the GM wish to play anything more, or less powerful. This is mentioned on p. 82 of the Core Rulebook (emphasis mine):

> **The Game Master may choose to run a campaign that uses a different Tier than the
>   ones presented here**. Adventures focused on juve gangers might have less than 100 starting build points, effectively acting as Tier 0. At the other extreme, a campaign that focused on a team of Space Marine Chapter Masters leading a Crusade alongside a Primarch could require 600 or more starting points for a Tier 6+. **These Tiers are entirely at the Game Master’s discretion.** They are best considered when developing a unique Framework that requires such extremes.

Additionally, there is also a "Quick NPC Table" (Core Rulebook, p. 408) that should be managed in a similar manner - if the Escalation Tier is at 6+, the same should be done for this table as well.